# C# Select from database random no repeat

Tags: c#, select

I have a script that select from database in random order.

The script is a simulation of auto exam. The thing I want is that if a question has already been selected, to not be extracted again.

How can I do that? Other thing, if no one of those 3 `checkboxes` were selected, when message box appear, it selects another question. `Select()` initialize labels with value from database and I use it in Load form.

Here is the Code what i have tried so far:

```
private void select()
{
     string dataA = "SELECT * FROM questions order by rand()";
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(dataA, index.connect);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     using (index.connect)
     {
        index.connect.Open();
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
           if (rdr.Read())
           {
               label2.Text = rdr["question"].ToString();
               label2.AutoSize = true;
               label2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
               label3.Text = rdr["answer1"].ToString();
               label4.Text = rdr["answer2"].ToString();
               label5.Text = rdr["answer3"].ToString();
               option1 = checkBox1.Checked;
               option2 = checkBox2.Checked;
               option3 = checkBox3.Checked;
            }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
         finally
         {
            index.connect.Close();
         }
      }
  }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
// in cazul in care raspunzi la o intrebare, 
//iar aceasta ramane, orice a-i raspunde, pune la incorect
{
    string dataA = "SELECT * FROM questions order by rand()";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(dataA, index.connect);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    using (index.connect)
    {
        index.connect.Open();
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            label2.Text = rdr["question"].ToString();
            label3.Text = rdr["answer1"].ToString();
            label4.Text = rdr["answer2"].ToString();
            label5.Text = rdr["answer3"].ToString();
            option1 = checkBox1.Checked;
            option2 = checkBox2.Checked;
            option3 = checkBox3.Checked;
            if (checkBox1.Checked == false && 
                checkBox2.Checked == false && 
                checkBox3.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bifati minim o casuta!");
                //imi selecteaza alta intrebare
                 return;
            }
            else
            {
               if ((option1.ToString() == rdr["option1"].ToString()) &&
                   (option2.ToString() == rdr["option2"].ToString()) && 
                   (option3.ToString() == rdr["option3"].ToString()))
               {
                    corect++;
                    label10.Text = corect.ToString();
                    checkBox1.Checked = false;
                    checkBox2.Checked = false;
                    checkBox3.Checked = false;
               }
               else
               {
                    incorect++;
                    label12.Text = incorect.ToString();
                    checkBox1.Checked = false;
                    checkBox2.Checked = false;
                    checkBox3.Checked = false;
               }
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use DISTINCT in the query ?

Comment: I don't know what's that..Can you explain to me and give me a hand?

Comment: Try this
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions order by rand()

Comment: And I have to check if all questions had been selected?

Comment: Because the simulation contains only 26 questions and in database I have over 1,000...

Comment: Add a flag to the table, for example: IsSelected as a boolean column
And in your query check if its false
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions WHERE IsSelected = false ...

Comment: Report question - correct choice is not selected properly. The questions repeated again and the correct answer is sometimes taken as incorrect.

Comment: And the value of checkboxes is stored in database as VARCHAR not as boolean

Comment: Instead of `order by rand()` try this `order by newid()`

Comment: `FUNCTION aplicatie.newid does not exist`..`aplicatie` is name of database

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using SQL Server.

Comment: The code is running well, until the questions is repeating. I just don't understand why

Comment: It's fine..If you have any idea, I'm open to any ideas

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application, or a website, or something else?

Comment: Windows form applications..c#

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the already selected questions from being returned to you.

To do this, you need to store the id of each question returned by your method in a collection and use that collection to exclude question for next selects.

Avoid using a flag in the database because that will work only if there is only one instance of application running. If there are multiple instances each instance will get different questions served and should exclude only questions received by it.

To exemplify:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
    public Answer[] Answers {get; set;}
}

public class QuestionSelector
{
    private readonly List<int> _previousQuestionIds = new List<int>();

    public Question NextQuestion()
    {
        var query = "select top 1 * from Questions ";
        if(ids.Any())
        {
            var ids = String.Join(",", _previousQuestionIds.Select(id=>id.ToString()));
            query += "  where id not in (" + ids + ") ";
        }
        query += " order by rand()";
        var question = ParseQuestion(query);
        _previousQuestionIds.Add(question.Id);
        return question;
    }

    private Question ParseQuestion(string query)
    {
        // query the database and convert the data from the returned row
    }
}
```

Having the above class just create an instance of it when loading your form and call `NextQuestion()` method to load the next question. It will start with an empty collection of ids meaning that on first call it won't exclude any question but each time you'll call the `NextQuestion()` method it will add the id of the returned question to the list and on the next call the question will be excluded.

Comment: Ok, but how can I do that in my code? There's too much code that have to be modified..

Comment: I mean, is possible to make it in my own script?

Comment: @Paulicaaa I don't know of any way to do that only with a script and if there were a way I don't think it will be a simple one because you'd need to know which questions were loaded for each user in order to build the exclusion list. I don't want to sound rude but looking at the code you posted and how much duplication is in there this sort of change would be worth your while in future.

Comment: I see..well, thank you very much for help, I appreciate and I'll try to create a good code :)